# tf rotation before translation?

Tags: ros, translation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot find any documentation on convention used by tf.

```
$ rosrun tf tf_echo /map /odom
At time 1263248513.809
- Translation: [2.398, 6.783, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.707, 0.707]
in RPY [0.000, -0.000, -1.570]
```

1. For translation value and rotation quaternion value,
   is translation happening in original frame and then rotation happens?
   Or, does it rotate first and then the translation happens?
   What is the convention used by tf system?
2. Which RPY convention is RPY using?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112231/tf-rotation-before-translation?/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS coordinate frame conventions are defined here: http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions

And the API methods are also documented such as here:
http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Matrix3x3.html#af2107031776762df1a0fea357b4c3747

1. It will translate first.
2. RPY is Fixed Axis XYZ

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2016-08-19**:
Could you please tell how to rotate before translating in one frame broadcast?

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-11-01**:
Create separate rotation and translation transforms and compose them, then broadcast the composed tf. E.g. in c++: `my_tf = my_translation * my_rotation;`

**Comment by [GXY](https://answers.ros.org/users/36948/gxy/) on 2019-12-07**:
Any way to do this in Python?